# JQuery addClass() function to surround input is not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to surround a form input with red when the word "Paris" is entered:

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="results.php" onsubmit="return submitForm(this);">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="tags" class="control-label">Destination</label>
    <input type="text" id="tags" name="tags" placeholder="place">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="control-label"></label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function submitForm(oFormElement) {
  var tags=$("#tags").val();

  if(tags=="Paris"){
    $("div.form-group").addClass("has-error");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

The problem is that only the word "Destination" gets red, but I need the input to be surrounded with red.

Thank you

Comment: Share your CSS as well

Answer (score 2):

Add error class to the input text box instead of entire div.

Please below code for your reference

```
$("div.form-group #tags").addClass("has-error");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom CSS like this,

```js
function submitForm(oFormElement) {


  var tags = $("#tags").val();

  if (tags == "Paris") {

    $("#tags").addClass("error");
    return false;

  }


  return true;
}
```

```css
.error {
  border-color: #FF0000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="results.php" onsubmit="return submitForm(this);">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="tags" class="control-label">Destination</label>
    <input type="text" id="tags" name="tags" placeholder="place">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="control-label"></label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
  </div>


</form>
```

Comment: Where do you put the js code? I tried your solution it does not work for me

Comment: @Henri add inside your script tag

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#tags').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === 'Paris') {
      $(this).addClass('has-error');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('has-error');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.has-error {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px red;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="results.php" onsubmit="return submitForm(this);">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="tags" class="control-label">Destination</label>
    <input type="text" id="tags" name="tags" placeholder="place">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="control-label"></label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
  </div>

</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```